# Single front NGINX to proxy pass SSL to sites with their own certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxypass

**Current setup:**

1. Front NGINX proxy passes 80 and 443 to local VM
2. Local VM's NGINX redirects everything to HTTPS (if request is HTTP/80)
3. Local VM's NGINX listens to 443 and proxy passes to the upstream backend

Front NGINX:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain1.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.24;
         }
}
```

Domain1.com's NGINX:

```
upstream unicorn_domain1.com {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.domain1.com.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com;

    ### REDIRECT EVERYTHING TO HTTPS
    return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;
    server_name domain1.com localhost;
    root /var/www/domain1.com/production/current/public;
    spdy_headers_comp 1;

    ### ALL THE CERT_ CONF HERE

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
    location @unicorn {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_domain1.com;
    }

    ### Omitted    
}
```

**Problem:**
Domain1 is a local network VM. This is currently the VM that has port 443 open to it. That means that only one site at the moment can listen on 443. That won't work when adding a second site. So we need the "front NGINX" to listen on port 443, and just proxy pass to the VMs, that use their own certificates.

**What I've tried:**
A seemingly normal proxy pass config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # Ensure your certificate is for nginx.domain.com;
    server_name domain1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.24;
    }
}
```

But this got us an `Connection refused` error (Chrome message). What am I missing? There shouldn't be any changes to Domain1.com's NGINX imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just declare "ssl" without setting SSL up properly. You need to provide certificates and private keys. I have a tutorial on [how to do that with Let's Encrypt here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/), or you can google "Nginx how enable SSL" and follow a beginners tutorial.

Config should end up looking something like this

```
listen 443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/site/fullchain;
ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/site/privkey;

# Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

# This is a cache for SSL connections
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
ssl_session_timeout 60m;
```

Comment: But the VMs do have their own certs (shown and omitted by ` ### ALL THE CERT_ CONF HERE`), which I want to use. I've seen examples where the front NGINX just passes it through. For example (https://serversforhackers.com/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru) but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did you make the `stream` configuration block like instructed in the article? Your question should be about your attempt making the article's solution work, which it isn't at the moment...

Comment: I wasn't sure if the article was the right way to go